# Honor EXIF tag on IIS

Tags: iis, internet-explorer, image, virtual-directory

Forgive me if this isn't the correct area, but figure I'd give it a shot.

I have a virtual directory mapped to a fileshare over IIS. On this fileshare are images. When viewing an image through the url, the image is sideways.

After a bit of research, I found this out...
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2001954

Apparently windows applications do not utilize the orientation property in the EXIF tag.

My question...is there anyway through IIS that allows you to honor this EXIF tag? So that the image will display in the correct orientation.

What's funny is that chrome can display the image correctly, just not IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "fast publish" (read: not quality controlled very well) KB article you linked is misleading. Many third-party Windows applications (like Chrome) handle the EXIF orientation flag just fine. The built-in picture viewer (at least through Windows 7) doesn't, but that's not "Windows"-- that's just an application. (That article is really, really cruddy...)

Having said that, you're thinking about this wrong. Generally speaking, you wouldn't want the web server (IIS) to be monkeying with the files it transfers dynamically. You *could* write some kind of monstrosity of code to detect if the user is running an IE browser and "fix" the image appropriately, but that really doesn't make any sense.

If you can modify these images persistently you could use any number of tools to "normalize" the orientation of all the images to be the same.